# How can I prove 'separable' guarantees 'second countable'?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces, second-countable

Separable means having a countable dense set and second countable means having a countable basis.

But I cannot find any relation between dense set and basis.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925731/separable-implies-second-countable/926236)

Comment: You can only prove it in a metric space. In any topological space the converse is true, so in a metric space they are equivalent.

Comment: Hint: Let A be a countable dense subset of X.
Take C to be the collection of all balls with rational radius around points in A.
Clearly C  is countable (cardinality $= |N|^2 = |N|$).
Show C is a basis for the topology of X:

Comment: Can I hear someone's explanation about triangle inequality in this proof ?

Comment: Continuing my earlier comment you use the triangle inequality to prove that C is a basis.

Comment: Are you talking about metric spaces or general topological spaces? A topological space can be separable (or even countable) without being second countable (or even first countable). But for metric spaces separable and second countable are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that all second-countable spaces are separable. The converse is not correct. For an example, take $\mathbb{R}$ in the lower limit topology, that is the one generated by intervals of the form $[a,b)$. The set $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers is dense but it is not second-countable (show this!).